# Changing the background of other link on hover of the First link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following mark up.

```
<ul>
<li><a><span>link-1</span></a></li>
<li><a><span>link-2</span></a></li>
<li><a><span>link-3</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

When user hover on the first 'a' then the next a tag in LI , we remove the backgorund-image.

I hope you are clear what I want to do with this.

Comment: Not particularly. I don't completely understand, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript - hurray for CSS skills!

You can do it with the [adjacent selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) (`+` CSS selector), try hovering on a link in your HTML while using this CSS:

```
ul li a {
    color: red
}
ul li:hover+li a {
    color: blue
}
```

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is a good testing ground.)

Why you'd want something with such a low usability is beyond my comprehension.
But perhaps it makes sence, in your scenario.

Comment: Very eloquent solution. Browser compatibility might be an issue though - http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t12

Answer (score 0):

Use [Jquery.mouseout()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) to remove the background.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this

```
$('#linka').mouseover(function() {
     $(this).attr('class','somethingrandom'); //so that you can change remaining with ease
     $('.remaininga').removeclass('yourclass'); //whether add a new or remove
}).mouseout(function() {
     $(this).attr('class','remaininga');  //to bring back to previous state
});
```

What you actually need to do from my point, is change the class name each time so that you can change the class of remaining

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

example

$('ul:eq(0) > li').css('background','none')